# Source code parsing and formatting

Tags: java

Problem:

1. Read a source code file(e.g .java)
2. Remove all empty lines from it
3. Remove all comments from it
4. Remove unnecessary spaces between loops
   Example

   ```
   for ( int i = 0, int j = 0   ; i < = data.length, j   <  44; i++ , j++)
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   for(int i=0,int j=4;i<=data.length,j<44;i++,j++)
   ```
5. Change braces in:

   ```
   void sleep(){
       return;
   }
   ```

   to

   ```
   void sleep()
   {
       return;
   }
   ```

I have made functions for **1** to **3** which work using regex.

But for **4**, I have written a separate String fixFor (String forCode) function and I have to modify all fors manually.
Does anyone know a programmatic solution i.e a Java program to do this without using find and replace functionality of a text editor?
I am reading my source code file into a String using:

```
    String s=new String(readAllBytes(get("Code.java")));
```

Also for **5**, it is easy to replace all `{` with `{\n` but then indentation does not remain valid.

Comment: Well, if you call `for(int i=0,int j=4;i<=data.length,j<44;i++,j++)` formatted, then I can only say: wow ...

Comment: Firstly,my question doesn't call for(int i=0,int j=4;i<=data.length,j<44;i++,j++) as formatted.It instead states to remove spaces in between.And secondly,if you are having a hard time time understanding this "formatted" for code,then I can only say,wow!

Comment: If you want to remove all whitespace simply replace \S with nothing and there you go! If thats too much, then i am sorry and don't understand why you want to do this in the first place :)

Comment: I don't have a hard time to understand that line, if have a hard time to understand why you think that removing *all* whitespaces (excepting the ones after a variable type) counts as formatted in the real world. But that's your decision and your source code. Do whatever you want with it.

Comment: 5. `line = line.replaceFirst("^(\\s*)(\\S.*)\\s*\\{\\s*$", "$1$2\n$1{");` for the correct indentation

Comment: @NoRelect If I do string.replaceAll("\\S",""),then the string goes empty.I think you meant using replaceAll("\\s","").But when I do so,it does remove all spaces but it kills the purpose because code no longer remains a source code anymore : )

Comment: @JoopEggen I am doing String s=new String(readAllBytes(get("Code.java"))); which reads my source code file into a String variablle.So if I do:
s=s.replaceAll("\\{", "\n{");
s=s.replaceFirst("^(\\s*)(\\S.*)\\s*\\{\\s*$", "$1$2\n$1{");
I get the same unindented output.

Comment: `s = s.replaceAll("\r?\n([ \t]*)(.*\\S)[ \t]*\\{[ \t]*(\r?\n)", "$1$2$3$1{");` should do.

Comment: @JoopEggen I tried this but it is giving me strange results.It is messing with all lines which come after { and puts tab spaces over there.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little vague as I'm unsure whether a solution code be simply to use a text editor with a macro or whether its source code in Java you need either way.

For 4 You could use a pattern to iterate through the line and find instances from a list of keywords in whatever language you are parsing and then subsequently handle whatever group has been found, whether this means replace the group within the string or copying them and reforming the original string keeping only matched groups unmodified:

```
/*
 * StackOverflow example
 * 
 * 
 */
package javaapplication5;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 *
 * @author dean2191
 */
public class JavaApplication5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String code = "for ( int i = 0, int j = 0   ; i < = data.length, j   <  44; i++ , j++) ";
        List yourKeywords = new ArrayList();
        yourKeywords.add("int");
        yourKeywords.add("boolean"); //any keywords,could read them from a file
        Iterator<String> iterator = yourKeywords.iterator();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(" + iterator.next() + "\\s"+"[a-zA-Z0-9]" + ")");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(code);

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println("group to keep found:"+m.group());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This code's output will be :

```
group to keep found:int i
group to keep found:int j
```

As mentioned above you could then copy this group and generate a new string making sure these groups are the only part not stripped of spaces if this is what you really want.

However depending on how much parsing you actually want to do to a language it may be worth while to consider a solution such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org) for a more robust parsing solution.

Comment: Your solution gave me the idea of splitting my source code into separate lines and then to check using if(line[i].contains("for(")) line[i]=fixFor(line[i]);